# Google App Script - Google-Sheet rows are not sorting by timestamp as expected

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using JavaScript to sort the rows in a Google Sheet by the timestamp column. However, the sorting does not work properly as the most latest timestamp does not show on the top as it should. My data format of the timestamp column in the google Sheet is set to Short Date (mm/dd/yyyy).

What is the issue?

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort({column: 1, ascending: false});
}
```

Output: (Note how the row with timestamp 9/3 should be on the top but it is not!)
[image]

Comment: What does `=isdate(A2)` return? Are there any errors logged in  Script editor>View> executions?

Comment: It returns TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

In this particular scenario, you can also take the full range and sort by that:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange().sort({column: 1, ascending: false});
}
```

**Restrictions:**

This method only works for `ascending: false`, otherwise it will sort the headers as well.

**References:**

[getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)

Comment: Headers would be a problem. Headers, if sorted, may go down. It  is undesirable.

Comment: I ran it and the headers stayed at the correct position. I can't reproduce the issue you are referring to. @TheMaster

Comment: even with `ascending: true`?

Comment: that's a different scenario. but I will specify it in my answer. @TheMaster

Comment: Even with `ascending:false`, it won't work with text data like"Using", "Zebra"(anything above `T`imestamp). The only reason it works now is because in ascii code, numbers are below text

Comment: The data the OP showed comes from a form . Timestamp will be the default header. Anyway, I see your point.

Answer (score 3):

Because you excluded A2 in your `getRange(3,..)` call(syntax: getRange(row, column, number of rows, number of columns)), A2 is excluded from the sort.

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1 + 1/*Modified*/, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1/*Modified*/, sheet.getLastColumn());
```

Comment: I vote up for this because it is a more generic workable solution :)